# Python: Input validate with string length

Tags: python, validation, input

Ok so i need to ensure that a phone number length is correct. I came up with this but get a syntax error.

```
phone = int(input("Please enter the customer's Phone Number."))
if len(str(phone)) == 11:
    else: phone = int(input("Please enter the customer's Phone Number."))
phonumber.append(phone)
```

Comment: i thought u ve indentation problem and i was trying to edit it :) but it was your code real error.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this to be asking for the phone number until it is correct:

```
phone = ""
while len(str(phone)) != 11:
    phone = int(input("Please enter the customer's Phone Number."))
phonumber.append(phone)
```

If you want to check also that the input is a number and not text, you should also trap the exception raised by `int` in that case, for example:

```
phone = ""
while len(str(phone)) != 11:
    try:
        phone = int(input("Please enter the customer's Phone Number."))
    except ValueError:
        phone = ""
phonumber.append(phone)
```

Comment: You could write the first line as `phone = ''`.

Comment: Since you won't be doing math with a phone number, it's in appropriate to convert it to an integer.

Comment: This is an accurate answer, but honestly it appears that OP doesn't know the most basic Python syntax. The difference between OP's knowledge level and the complexity of this answer makes this Q&A unhelpful imo. Answers aren't for writing code for people. For that reason @jonrsharpe's answer may actually be more on-topic for the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have

```
if:
    else:
```

Because the `else`, being inside the first `if` block, doesn't have a corresponding `if`.

It should be:

```
if:
    this
else:
    that
```